# Bundler: "Could not find bson-1.4.0 in any of the sources"

Tags: rubygems, amazon-ec2, mongoid, bundler, bson

I'm trying to do a `bundle install` but I'm getting the error 
`Could not find bson-1.4.0 in any of the sources`.
I believe bson-1.4.0 is a requirement for mongoid ~> 2.0 which is in my Gemfile.

When I try `gem install -v 1.4.0 bson`, I get the error

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bson' (= 1.4.0), here is why:
          Found bson (1.4.0), but was for platform jruby
```

the bundle install works fine on my development machine (running OSX 10.6.8), but I'm having this problem on a 64-Bit Amazon EC2 instance.

If I try requesting an earlier version, then do a `bundle update`, I get the error

`Could not find gem 'bson (= 1.4.0) x86-mingw32', which is required by gem 'mongo (~> 1.3) x86-mingw32', in any of the sources.`

could it be because of it being 64bit? Any possible workarounds?

running rails 3.0.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this exact problem earlier today.  It turns out v1.4 and v1.4.1 have been removed from rubygems.org.  I managed to get around it by downloading the gem files manually and installing to the app.

http://tinyurl.com/3fksky8

Comment: got it, thanks for the link that explained what's going on! I think it's best if we wait for v1.4.2 for now.