# Rails 3 and mongoid setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm trying to follow the Railscasts on mongoid

http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid

When I install the mongoid and bson_ext gem it seems fine, but each time that I run a rails command, like:

```
rails g scaffold article name:string content:text
```

I get a warning in the console:

```
Able to load bson_ext version 1.3.1, but >= 1.4.1 is required.
```

But I can't find a bson_ext 1.4.1, current version seems to be 1.3.1 in the rubygems directory.

Is there an other step that I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run

```
gem update bson_ext
```

Comment: I did that before with bundle update. when I run this it returns "nothing to update". http://rubygems.org/gems/bson_ext is at 1.3.1

Comment: bundle update won't do anything because your Gemfile.lock file is pointing at version 1.3.1.  Try removing your Gemfile.lock, then running "gem update bson_ext", then bundling again.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer to that bson 1.4 mistery

http://rubygems.org/gems/bson/versions/1.4.1-jruby

need to be installed with the -v flag

```
gem install bson -v 1.4.1
```

Default bson is 1.3, and ~> 1.4 has been pulled out from gems repo. Need to be download and installed manually. But they recommend to wait for 1.4.2 .

Issue is referenced here too:

[Bundler: "Could not find bson-1.4.0 in any of the sources"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939362/bundler-could-not-find-bson-1-4-0-in-any-of-the-sources)